# How to compile Cordova Apps for older Android versions

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

I have installed cordova-android version 7.0.0

My app must run in Android 4.1.1

So I added the platform with:

```
cordova platform add android@4.1.1
```

Then I get:

> Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@4.1.1 Adding android
>   project... Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Unhandled
>   "error" event. (Does not appear to implement platform Api.) Error:
>   Package name must look like: com.company.Name

Any advice?

Answer (score 8):

The original question has been edited and it ask for Android 4.1.1 (SDK 16) support now and not SDK 19 as the original answer.

To support Android 4.1.1 you can use cordova-android 7.0.0 or older, cordova-android 7.1.0 increased the Min SDK to 19.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

First of all, even latest cordova-android version (7.1.0 at the moment), still supports SDK 19 and newer, so not sure why do you want to downgrade to 4.1.1.

Now, to get cordova-android 4.1.1 working you need an old Cordova CLI, because new CLIs require new platforms and are not compatible with very old one such as 4.1.1.

So install Cordova CLI 5.4.1 with

```
npm install -g cordova@5.4.1
```

After doing that, you should be able to add cordova-android 4.1.1 with

```
cordova platform add android@4.1.1
```

Comment: If I undesrtand correctly, what was changed in cordova android 7.0 is not the target sdk (sdk used to build) as in every new build but the minimum sdk (the minimum version a phone needs to be able to run the app). So apps made with cordova android 7.0 or newer will not run on phone that have an android version older than 4.4 that's why many people need to keep using older versions.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand the 4.1.1 part, I though he was trying to install cordova-android 4.1.1, but what he wants is to support cordova-android 4.1.1. Anyway, the min SDK bump was done in cordova-android 7.1.0, so 7.0.0 still supports 4.1.0 and newer.

Comment: min sdk was changed in 7.0 and specific code for earlier version was removed in 7.1 so I assume it was already not working in 7.0 https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html

Comment: ah ok just saw your comment in my answer about the "by mistake" :)

Comment: @QuickFix, BTW, I answered before the question was edited, the OP was asking for SDK 19 support and didn't mention anything about supporting Android 4.1.1, but the one offering the bounty hijacked and completely changed the question, so my answer no longer makes sense to current question.

Answer (score 8):

Cordova android platform version is not the same as the android version your phone needs to be runing.

A version of cordova platform supports a range of android OS versions. You can find an array of supported Android versions for each cordova android platform version on [the Codova Android platform guide page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html).

Cordova android platform versions 6.x supported android versions from 4.1 to 7.1.

For cordova android platform version 7.x the minimum version has been set to 4.4 so platform version 7.x can't be used if you need to support phones older than Kit-Kat (the minimum sdk was changed).

All that to say that what you need is a version 6 of cordova platform tools not 4.1.1, so with the following line, it should work fine with :

```
cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

I haven't tested latest version of the CLI, for the moment I'm still using cordova version 7.0.1 with android platform 6.2.3, so I'm not sure if cordova android 6.4.0 will work with cordova 8 or if you will have to downgrade also the CLI version.

Comment: the min SDK was supposed to be bumped in cordova-android 7.0.0, but wasn't done by mistake. So 7.0.0 still supports SDK 16 and newer. cordova-android 7.1.0 supports SDK 19 and newer.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. Can also run `cordova platform add android@6` if we dont remember exact verison.

Answer (score 3):

Install Andorid platform API level 19 from Android SDK Manager

Install stable cordova:

```
npm install -g cordova@7.0.0

cordova platform add android
```

Add this inside `<widget>...<widget/>` in config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19">
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19">
```

Make the below changes in `build.gradle`:

```
defaultMinSdkVersion=16
defaultTargetSdkVersion=19 
defaultCompileSdkVersion=19
```

Make the below change in `project.properties`:

```
target=android-19
```

Run your code:

```
cordova run android
```

Comment: why did you do all that? All cordova-android versions support SDK 19 and newer, using an old target SDK is a bad idea, it will work fine in SDK 19 devices, but not so good in newer devices, it's not recommended to change the target SDK. The version determining the lower android version supported is `android-minSdkVersion`, but as I said, if you want SDK 19 as min, that's the version used by latest released cordova-android

Answer (score 2):

Please update node and cordova as latest one.

```
npm install -g cordova
```

and add android 6.2.3 version.

```
cordova platform add android@6.2.3
```

This version will work great now.

Answer (score 1):

Add crosswalk to your project can support Android version 4.1.1

Firstly, `ionic cordova platform remove android`

Then, `ionic cordova platform add android@6.2.3`

Finally,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is full of bad answers.**

[This page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) shows the versions of `cordova-android` and their compatible Android SDK APIs.  If you want to support Jelly Bean you need to use `cordova-android` version `6.x.x` – The latest versions (`7.x.x`) only support down to API level 19 (v4.4 called Kit Kat).  There's no reason to do any of this other crazy stuff!

Just run `cordova platform remove android && cordova platform add android@6`

Make sure your cordova updated too with `npm i -g cordova`, it works fine without downgrading.  Also keep in mind you no longer need the `cordova-plugin-compat` package!

Also note that you need to download a different SDK API than 16, but it will still work on older devices, like Android 4.1.1.